# Simultaneous public and private credential access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I have received a username, access key ID, and secret access key ID for a public dataset on Amazon S3 (public for authorised users). I have been using `s3cmd` with my private account and S3 buckets. How can I configure `s3cmd` so that at the same time I can access my previous private credentials, and the new public data credentials I have received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When first configuring `s3cmd` you probably ran `s3cmd --configure` and input your access and secret keys. This saves the credentials to a file `~/.s3cfg` looking something like this:

```
[default]
access_key=your_access_key
...bunch of options...
secret_key=your_secret_key
```

`s3md` accepts the `-c` flag to point at a config file. Set up two config files, one with your first set of credentials (for example, `~/.s3cfg-private`) and one with the other set (for example, `~/.s3cfg-public`). Then you can use:

```
s3cmd -c ~/.s3cfg-public s3://my-public-bucket
s3cmd -c ~/.s3cfg-private s3://my-private-bucket
```

For convenience, leave the credentials you need most frequently in the file named `~/.s3cfg` as it will be used by default.